# Song plays first time but does not play once stopped : Clip in Java

Tags: java, audio, clip

I am using Clip in java to play a song as follows:

```
        MR.clip= (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(MR.info[docIdOfSelectedSong]);
        MR.clip.open(MR.sounds[docIdOfSelectedSong]);
        MR.clip.setMicrosecondPosition(5* 1000000);
        MR.clip.start();
```

where MR.sounds is an array of type `AudioInputStream` and MR.info is an array of type `DataLine.info`.  When I press a button ,the above code is called to play the song. Moreover, I have another button to stop the song which calls the below code

```
public static void stopSong(){

    MR.clip.close();

}
```

The problem is that when I play the song for the first time, the play and stop button are working fine. But, when I try to play the song for the second time, I cannot hear the  song. Any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like all other InputStreams, AudioInputStream can only be read once (unless it can be [.reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29)).  You could try calling .reset() on the AudioInputStream before attemping to play the sound again, but AudioInputStream may not support .reset().  InputStreams are not required to support reset.  Also see [markSupported()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported%28%29).

If .reset() doesn't work, consider constructing a new AudioInputStream every time you need to start playing.

---

UPDATE: I made an example of caching sound data in memory and using Clip to play those sounds.  This example utilizes AudioInputStream.reset().  So how can that work?  In fact, AudioInputStream *does* supports reset() *if and only if* its underlying InputStream supports .reset().  So my example creates an AudioInputStream that is backed by a ByteArrayInputStream.  Because ByteArrayInputStream supports reset, these cached AudioInputStreams also support .reset(), which allows them to be reused.

Note that if you are going to be playing any one cached sound concurrently, you should probably not cache `AudioInputStream`s, but rather cache `byte[]`s and construct an `AudioInputStream` per-playback.  This is because `AudioInputStream` is stateful, so passing a single instance of it to two concurrently running clips, or resetting a stream while one clip is playing, will result in state conflict.

```
public class CachedSoundClipTest
{
    static ArrayList<AudioInputStream> cachedSounds = 
        new ArrayList<AudioInputStream>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File[] audioFiles = new File("/audio_storage_directory").listFiles();
        for (File file : audioFiles)
        {
            AudioInputStream reusableAudioInputStream = 
                createReusableAudioInputStream(file);
            cachedSounds.add(reusableAudioInputStream);
        }

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Press enter to play next clip");
            BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            br.readLine();
            playCachedSound(0);
        }
    }

    private static void playCachedSound(int i) 
        throws IOException, LineUnavailableException
    {
        AudioInputStream stream = cachedSounds.get(i);
        stream.reset();
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(stream);
        clip.start();
    }

    private static AudioInputStream createReusableAudioInputStream(File file) 
        throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException
    {
        AudioInputStream ais = null;
        try
        {
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
            int read = 0;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = 
                new ByteArrayOutputStream(buffer.length);
            while ((read = ais.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
            {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            AudioInputStream reusableAis = 
                new AudioInputStream(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()),
                        ais.getFormat(),
                        AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED);
            return reusableAis;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ais != null)
            {
                ais.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, reset is not supported. What do you mean by consider constructing a new AudioInputStream? Can you give me an example using CLip

Comment: How do you create the AudioInputStreams to begin with?  Just do again what you did to initialize the AudioInputStream[] array.  But do it right before you play the clip.

Comment: Oh! I thought I can just read the AudioInputStream in the beginning of the program and keep re-using it

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to say.  "AudioInputStream can only be read once" also means "AudioInputStream can only be used once" which also means "it cannot be reused."

Comment: @Programmer I updated my answer with a working example of reusable cached AudioInputStreams

Comment: @MikeClark: I implemented your code for reusing a stream using a .wav file as an embedded resource. It plays the first time but it won't play again. I called AudioInputStream.reset() but no love. Is it because its a resource or did I do something wrong? See my pastebin (I don't think it warrants a question here):http://pastebin.com/rHk0Mus6. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeClark: My mistake I missed a fair-sized chunk of your code.

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to reset the current position of the clip to the start.

```
clip.stop();
clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
clip.start();
```

With this method, it is not necessary to load the same resource multiple times. The clip should only be loaded once and be stored as instance variable or something.

Answer (score 3):

In your code example, using a Clip, you should use the stop() method instead of the close() method. Then, when you restart, it will pick up where it left off. If you want to restart from the beginning, then you can use the setMicrosecondPosition() or setFramePosition() to 0, and use start().

See: "Using a Clip" in the tutorial below for more details!

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html

The SourceDataLine can only be used once and can't be reset. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on OS X, where the clip was sometimes not playing if you tried to stop it while it was playing, then restart it from the beginning. It was fixed by calling `flush()` right after `stop()`:

```
if(clip.isActive() || clip.isRunning()) {
    clip.stop();
    clip.flush();
}
```

Definitely don't use `close()`, use `stop()` if you want to be able to play your clip again.