# Java Detecting when sound stops

Tags: java, audio

I have a sound class for my application and it plays a certain sound when I tell it too. I want to be able to detect when the sound is finished playing so I can then play a different sound without them over lapping here is my sound class:

```
public class Sound {

public static final Sound cash = new Sound("/cash.wav");
public static final Sound snap = new Sound("/snap.wav");
public static final Sound disarm = new Sound("/disarm.wav");
public static final Sound tp = new Sound("/tp.wav");
public static final Sound select = new Sound("/selectBTN.wav");
public static final Sound scroll = new Sound("/btn.wav");
public static final Sound fire = new Sound("/fire2.wav");

private AudioClip c;

public Sound(String filename) {
    try {
        c = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(filename));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void play() {
    try {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                if (!title.mute) {

                    c.play();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

then to play the sound I use this line of code:

```
   Sound.cash.play();
```

How can I detect when the sound is finished playing

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (is an aproximation), with LineListener to detect the end of playing:

```
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent.Type;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

    public class Sound {


        private Clip                    c;

        public Sound(final String filename) {
            try {
                c = AudioSystem.getClip();
                final AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResourceAsStream(filename));
                c.open(inputStream);
                c.addLineListener(new LineListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void update(final LineEvent event) {
                        if (event.getType().equals(Type.STOP)) {
                            System.out.println("Do something");
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void play() {
            c.start();
        }

        public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            final Sound s = new Sound("/cash.wav");
            s.play();
            Thread.sleep(100000);
            final Sound p = new Sound("/cash.wav");
            p.play();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works but for some reason once I play a sound it wont play again how can I fix this

Comment: Its seems that you can reuse the same Sound object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999961/song-plays-first-time-but-does-not-play-once-stopped-clip-in-java